# Unable to paste in to filtered cells, error message "you can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size"

Tags: excel, paste

I have two spreadsheets, one of them is a list of events taking place this year and one is a calendar that has a row for all 365 days per year.

I had put the event names in to the calendar and then filtered that sheet so that only rows with event titles entered are visible using the dropdown on the header row.

I now want to copy and paste the rest of the event information over in batch without having to do it line by line and so selected the appropriate column and used Find & Select-> Go to Special...->Selected Visible Cells only but when I then try to paste to those visible cells I get the error message:

"You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again."

I've checked that I'm copying 230 rows and I've selected 230 rows, I've even tried resizing the cells so they're the same dimensions but I just get the same error every time. If I only select one cell then it pastes the data in to the invisible cells as well.

I've tried googling the error message but not found a solution that works so any help will be much appreictaed.

Comment: Size here refers to the dimensions of the range (for example 5 columns by 7 rows), and not the height and width of the cells on the screen. Excel is not very smart in this, so you can probably copy if you remove any filtering, grouping from your worksheet.

Comment: Thanks Laszlo, but if I remove the filtering then I have to go through and paste it line by line as there will be blanks on the dates with no events yet, there must be a way to paste in to visible cells only

Comment: You must use a workaround because this is really not possible no matter how easy it seems. Just an idea: introduce a "key" column with a unique identifier that's also defining the original order of the rows, then sort your entire table by the data you want to copy over, do the copy, then sort it again by the "key" column to restore the original view.

What you're seeking is only achievable by writing a macro, which requires some Visual Basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the VBA code I need to do this here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2617-excel-paste-to-visible-filtered-cells.html